# Problema al obtener información sobre el usuario actual en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando conseguir el nombre del usuario logueado en wordpress para verificar si dejarle entrar a la página o no.
Tengo el siguiente código en la **misma página** (pagina.php):

```
global $current_user;
// Compruebo que haya un usuario logueado:
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    // Obtengo la info sobre el usuario logeado:
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

    $user = $currentUser->user_login;

    // Si no es el Admin, lo redirecciono al index.
    if ($user != 'Admin') {
        // code  
    } 
}
```

El problema es que cuando entro a la página esta está **en blanco**.
¿A qué puede deberse el problema?, ¿puede tener relación por el "orden de carga" de las páginas de WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es controlar las paginas que carga, te recomiendo que ejecutes ese código en el archivo header.php siempre y cuando sea un tema hijo o un tema propio. A mi tu código no me deja la pagina en blanco al ejecutarlo desde el archivo que te digo.
Es más, en el header.php no neceistas llamar a la global $current_user.

La pagina en blanco será posiblemente por permisos.

Comment: Lo que me gustaría controlar es que tipo de usuario es el que accede a la página, de forma que, si no es el administrador lo redirecciones a otro lado, por ejemplo, el index.    He tenido que crear una página y añadirla a mi tema de wordpress, escrita por mi y estructurada toda por mí.  El problema es que cuando coloco el código que comento en mi pregunta, la página no carga.